# Preventing grey background to raster gplot with log scaled colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plotting a raster using `gplot()` yields a nice map, e.g:
[image]

Since the variable scale (population) covers many orders of magnitude, a log scale is preferred.  But when this is applied to the colour variable (by adding a `trans='log'` argument to `scale_fill_gradient`), the areas of zero population end up grey:

[image]

Does anyone know how to prevent this?  This is the code I'm using:

```
require(raster, rgdal, ggplot2)
pop = readGDAL("usa_population.tif")
p = raster(pop, layer=1, values=TRUE)
s <- stack(p)
gplot(s) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'blue', trans='log')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my guess: na.value="grey50" being used for log(0) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `na.value` argument of `scale_fill_gradient` to the appropriate value, e.g. `'white'`. The `NA`'s are caused by `log`, i.e. `log(0) = -Inf` which is interpreted as `NA` in `ggplot2`.

Comment: -Inf but I guess it becomes NA in ggplot?

Comment: Yes, `-Inf` is interpreted the same as `NA`.

Comment: Thanks. Should've spotted that one!

Comment: You can use "transparent" as a value as well as a color.